# The description failed to render for 'text/markdown'- PyPi

Tags: python, twine

I try to upload my library to pip.
At final stage I got that error.

HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
The description failed to render for 'text/markdown'. See https://pypi.org/help/#description-content-type for more information.

My Codes [here](https://github.com/gncll/body-calculator)

To check  my error I did that;

`twine check dist/*`

Output;

`Checking dist/Body-calculater-0.0.1.tar.gz: PASSED`

I tried to find the solution for over 2 hours but I can not get a clear answer.
I use Mac, Visual Studio- Python.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `README.md` (Must not be empty)

Delete `dist`, `*.egg-info`, and then again build the package.

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

Now, it should work.